# Clean up code when Ctrl+C is caught in python

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

By registering the signal handler, I can put my clean up code in signal_handler

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

But the problem is when user presses ctrl+c multiple times, the signal handler run multiple times and the clean up goes crazy.

**My problem is that, how can I make sure that the clean up handler is being ran once only before exit.**

Here is my trial using lock, but deadlock is occured

```
def cleanup_handler():
    lock.acquire()
    if not done:
        try:
            cleanup()
            done = True
        finally:
            print "release lock"
            lock.release()
```

The problem is that finally block is never ran (that is I can't see the "release lock" being printed).

**Remark**
After doing a little experiment, it seems that the signaler handler is not being ran at the same time. When new Ctrl+C is received, the old handler is killed and a new handler is ran. Am I correct? If yes, the problem becomes more complicated as I don't want my handler ends in the middle of the....

Comment: Is there a reason to use a signal handler instead of handling the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a decorator that prevents your function from being run more than once:

```
from functools import wraps

def run_once(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args):
        if not wrapper.has_run:
            wrapper.has_run = True

            return function()

    wrapper.has_run = False

    return wrapper
```

Like so:

```
@run_once
def signal_handler():
    print 'Exit'
```

Comment: I think my code is similar to you, use a boolean to store is the run finished. But it doesn't work

Comment: I setup a simple test case with `signal.signal` and it works for me. Could you explain how it doesn't work?

Comment: For my code,  print "release lock" is never ran which means the lock is not being released and so that deadlock.

Comment: After doing a experiment, it seems that the handler is not being ran at the same time. When new Ctrl+C is received, the old handler is end and run a new handler. Am I correct?

Comment: The decorator just prevents your function from running twice. The second, third, fourth, etc. calls just do nothing.